# FileStream Events not being fired

Tags: actionscript-3, air

To save and load character objects I am using File Stream in AIR, it is being targeted as an iPad app.

Event.complete is not firing and IOErrorEvent sometimes fires, I am at a loss.

Character class http://pastebin.com/pr6LSvMi

Thanks

-Anim8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things:

1. Don't post your code on other sites. Post it directly in the question. This will ensure that the code is available for as long as StackOverflow is, whereas Pastebin could disappear tomorrow rendering this question useless in the archives
2. In AS3, all object (including function) names should be lowerCaseCamelCase, class names should be UpperCaseCamelCase, constants should be UPPERCASE_UNDERSCORE_SEPARATED, and package names should be alllowercase. It won't cause any errors if you don't follow those, but they are the standard and we liked to point those out to devs here.
3. You must **always** add your event listeners prior to the load for any object (be it `URLLoader`, `Loader`, `FileStream`, etc. Basically, there is a small chance that the load will finish prior to the event listener being added, meaning the event listener won't even fire (extremely uncommon, but I have seen it happen with disk reads). Additionally, do not call `FileStream.close()` until *after* the load has finished. The latter is, I believe, your problem. You are closing your connection before the connection has completed its load.

So, remove `fsR.close()` from

```
fsR.openAsync(fR, FileMode.READ);
fsR.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadExistingCharacterObject);
fsR.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, CreateNewCharacterObject);
fsR.close();
```

And add it to the handlers, `LoadExistingCharacterObject` and `CreateNewCharacterObject`. Additionally, you need to do the same in `SaveCharacter`. Any time you use `FileStream.openAsync()`, you cannot `close` the stream until *after* the load has completed or errored out. If you use `FileStream.open()`, you can close it immediately afterward since the application execution stops while the load is completed (`FileStream.open()` is a synchronous operation and `FileStream.openAsync()` is asynchronous)

You should read the [LiveDocs for `FileStream`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html).